# GRASS 7 - raster calculator "and"

Tags: raster, grass-gis, raster-calculator

I am struggling with one thing in the raster calculator in GRASS GIS 7: 
I want to create a raster_b from raster_a, with raster_a values between >=-0.15 and <=0.15. The raster containing values <-0.15 I calculated with 
if("raster_a"  >0.05 , raster_b, null()),

but how do If((raster_a >-0.15) and (raster_a <0.15), raster_b, null))?

Any help is appreciated!
Peter

Comment: I can't say for sure, because I don't use GRASS, but if it's calculator is like the one in Whitebox GAT then, your statement would have to be: If(AND((raster_a >-0.15), (raster_a <0.15)), raster_b, null))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formulation is (for GRASS 6.x and GRASS 7):

```
if expression = True -> value of raster_a  
if expression = False -> nothing (null())
```

and:

```
resulting_layer = (expression, True, False)
```

so:

```
raster_b = (if..., raster_a, null())
```

- In the GRASS shell:

  r.mapcalc 'raster_b = if(raster_a > -0.15 && raster_a <0.15 ,raster_a,null())'
- with the Raster Map Calculator:

[image]

Comment: Gene, thank you - that is the solution! Highly apprieciated!